# Media Query in rails/bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting a media query to work in bootstrap ( using rails). Below is the media query

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {

   .center.navbar .nav, .center.navbar .nav > li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
     vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
    }

  .center .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  text-align:left;

   }

 .center .dropdown.open ul {

 display: block;

   }
```

The above media query is overriding all default behaviour no matter what the screen size is.I have received some advice from @baptme (thanks so much) to explain what is happening (which I now understand), basically because the query is using two classes and the default behaviour uses 1 class then the media query overrides. So my question is how do I get the media query to work only when the screen size is below 768px in this example and override the default styles when not

However this is where I get a little confused as when inspecting the elements in Firebug the defaults are as follows

```
      .center.navbar .nav, .center.navbar .nav > li {
       display: inline-block;
       float: none;
       vertical-align: top;
       }

      .center .dropdown-menu {
      text-align: left;
        }
```

Can anyone shed any more light on this, any help appreciated, if you would like to see it in action go to

```
     http://46.32.253.11/
```

Comment: after looking http://46.32.253.11/ I realised you must use @media (min-width: 980px) because you use bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: Hi again @baptme, ok so the navabr is fine on a desktop full screen, its when the responsive navbar button comes into effect, thats when the navbar gets messy.im sure you have noticed.. What i am trying to achieve is that when the navbar button is pressed all links are aligned to the left or center of page with no dropdown links showing, when a link is clicked the dropdowns will be revealed

Comment: at the moment the links are spread unevenly with all dropdowns showing

Answer (score 2):

From your example:

This will hide the dropdown, remove the black hover and display the links one under the other aligned on the left:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  .navbar  .dropdown-menu {display:none}
  .navbar .nav > li a:hover { background-color:transparent}
  .center.navbar .nav, .center.navbar .nav > li {display: table;clear:both};
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks so much @baptme, cantthank you enough,i guess this can go in my application.css file in rails? or does this still need to go into bootstrap.override.css

Comment: @Richlewis boostrap.override.css will be fine as long as it's after bootstrap.css

Comment: Hi @baptme, thanks again for your help, this does work, but cannot open any links in the dropdown when the media query is active. any ideas?